# Virtualbox doesn't work after update arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I made an update to my arch-linux, then I tried to run virtualbox, I got this error message:

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing '/sbin/vboxconfig'
```

When I tried to execute the command, I got:

```
/sbin/vboxconfig: No such file or directory
```

Also I tried `modprobe vboxdrv`, and got the message:

```
Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.13-1-ARCH
```

Any help for the problem!

Comment: modprobe won't work, since each time You replace kernel You need to recompile (or compile 1st time) it's driver. How about just installiing fresh virtualbox with pacman?

Comment: More information please, what packages did you update that broke vbox? have you rebooted since the update?

Comment: I update the system and install last version of kernel.

Comment: Yes, i rebooted after the update

Comment: Try `sudo vboxreload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel modules are installed on a per-version basis.  After you upgrade to a new kernel version, you need to re-install the VirtualBox modules (and any other out-of-tree modules, such as closed-source video drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the kernel version 4.9. You will have some kernel modules installed for your specific kernel, e.g. `linux49-virtualbox-host-modules`. If you upgrade to kernel version 4.15, you need to go install `linux415-virtualbox-host-modules`.

Keep in mind, the specific drivers you might need may very. For instance, you may need `linux415-virtualbox-guest-modules` instead. Just check which ones you had in use before and download the corresponding versions for your new kernel.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but had been voted down.